# How to send F10 with gtkterm?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, serial-port, serial-console

How can I send F1..F12 especially F10 in [gtkterm](https://github.com/Jeija/gtkterm)?
I have to press `F10` at the right moment to select the boot menu of an APU2 system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but don't use `gtkterm`.

Use eg. `screen /dev/ttyS0` from a terminal, and if that terminal is the "GNOME Terminal", disable the F10 accelerator key from Edit -> Preferences.

If you insist on using `gtkterm`, you may try pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>~</kbd> in order, but it may not work if don't press them fast enough ;-)

Update:

Alternatively, add a `macros = F5::<literal-esc>[21~` line in the `[default]` section of `~/.gtktermrc` and then press F5 in order to send an F10:

```
$ perl -ne 'print; print "macros  = F5::\e[21~\n" if /^\[default/' -i  ~/.gtktermrc
```